# Separate Reducers in Redux in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a 3 components namely pending orders, approved orders and cancelled orders.  My question is do i have to create a separate state for them in reducers. Like pendingOrders, approvedOrders, cancelledOrders OR do i just include them all in a state called orders. What will be the ideal way to do this?

Comment: Reducers should be based on something like users, employees, products and so on. In your case they are just orders hence the reducer should be one only. In case you have a separate concern regarding users then only you should have users and orders.

Comment: I would suggest to create 3 seperate reducers as the code would be more readable . Currently, you only have 3 components.But consider a scenario where you're application has 30 components. Having all the reducer logic in a single file would be too chaotic. So if you just create reducers based on the component, it can be easily maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would organize my Store / Reducer by context and if needed (for performance reasons) I would compute and keep the filtered ids in the same Store's item (orders) as child props.

So I would start with something like that, *following [Redux state organization best practices](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state) and [Normalazing State Shape recipe](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)*:

```
{
  orders: {
    byIds: {
      1: { id: 1, status: 'pending' },
      2: { id: 2, status: 'approved' },
      3: { id: 2, status: 'cancelled' },
    } 
  }
}
```

And only if there are performance reasons getting orders by status, then I will compute and cache the result as follows:

```
{
  orders: {
    byIds: {
      1: { id: 1, status: 'pending' },
      2: { id: 2, status: 'approved' },
      3: { id: 3, status: 'cancelled' },
    },
    pending: [1],
    approved: [2],
    cancelled: [3],
  }
}
```